# Celery task returning result to parent task

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery web scraping task where I want to return all the created children objects back to the parent. How can I get these ids back to the parent?

Rough example of what i'm trying todo

```
@task
def scrape_page(url):
    page = Page.objects.create(
        name='new_page'
    )

    response = requests.get(url)
    children = parse_children(response)

    for child in children:
        result = scrape_child.delay(child.url)
        page.childen.add(result)

@task
def scrape_child(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    parsed = parse_child(response)
    child = Child.objects.create(**parsed)
    return child
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't wait for a delayed a task inside a task, you can call the task synchronously with `.apply()` but this will not call a separated task.
Edit: i found the docs, see [Avoid launching synchronous subtasks](http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks)

Maybe you should use [group](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#group). An approach is to delay a group `scrape_child` tasks and sending the parent `page_id`

```
from celery import group

@task
def scrape_page(url):
    page = Page.objects.create(
        name='new_page'
    )

    response = requests.get(url)
    children = parse_children(response)

    children_group = group([
        scrape_child.s(page.id, child.url)  # using the signature
        for child in children
    ])
    children_group.delay()
    return True

@task
def scrape_child(page_id, url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    parsed = parse_child(response)
    child = Child.objects.create(**parsed)
    child.page_id = page_id
    return child
```